# NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here's my error:

```
NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists[Project.Core.Entities.User#(GUID)]
at Hibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.DefaultEntityNotFoundDelegate.HandleEntityNotFound(String entityName, Object id) 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
```

One of the users of the system chanced upon getting this error, which doesn't make sense to me entirely. What I do know:

1. A Teacher table REFERENCES a User table.
2. Somehow the Teacher table has a row that references to a row in the User's table, but that row doesn't exist in the User's table.

Any idea why is this happening? Please advise!

Rephrase my Qn:

I know what does the error meant, however I don't seem to figure out what caused the missing user row? I have placed it all on Cascade.ALL. I don't think it's related to deletion. What are the possible scenarios the above may happen?

Edit 2:

Please refer to the mapping via FNH: Any issues with this?

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Teacher> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References(x => x.User).Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. Can you elaborate on what you have done to troubleshoot this or what is unclear? Is the user present in the table?

Comment: @OskarBerggren, slight rephrased. :)

Answer (score 4):

I set the 'Not Found' property to 'Ignore'

Answer (score 3):

In Fluent NHibernate for C#, I've used

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Bars).Table("foobars")
                        .ParentKeyColumn("FooId")
                        .ChildKeyColumn("Id")
                        .NotFound.Ignore();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missching a FK constrain in your database, otherwise you will not have any missing records on a FK relation. Add the FK and Cascade rules in your database, then you cann't have any 'missing row exceptions'. A error will be raised when you try to do something which is not in line with your database model.

Comment: Hi, I have added a portion of my FNH mapping. Anything wrong with the mapping? Please kindly advise. Thanks!

Comment: Is the foreign key relationship defined in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try that...

```
public void Override(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    modelMapper.Class<T>(c => { 
        c.ManyToOne(m => m.FKObj, r => {
            r.Column("FKColumn");
            r.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore); // THIS IS IMPORTANT!!!
        });
    });
}
```

Or this... if you have an "Conventions" file...

First handles the BeforeMapManyToOne event:

```
mapper.BeforeMapManyToOne += Mapper_OnBeforeMapManyToOne;
```

And then set the NotFound to Ignore by default...

```
private static void Mapper_OnBeforeMapManyToOne(IModelInspector modelInspector, PropertyPath propertyPath, IManyToOneMapper manyToOneMapper) {
    manyToOneMapper.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `.hbm.xml` mapping file then the "not found" setting can be applied in there to the mapping, e.g.

`<many-to-one name="User" column="User" not-found="ignore" />`